# вернуть input значение disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Есть чекбокс и инпут. По нажатию на чекбокс, инпут становится активным. Но когда чекбокс отключаешь, инпут не становится снова disabled, а продолжает быть активным. Подскажите, как сделать чтобы инпут вновь стал выключенным. Вот код:

```js
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("click", function() {
    var dataClass = $(this).data("class");
    $(".js-all").each(function() {
      this.disabled = !$(this).hasClass(dataClass);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checker squaredFour">
  <label>
     <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-test" data-class="js-a">
     <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
   </label>
</div>

<label for="inputReturn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Обратно</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker js-all js-a" id="inputReturn" disabled>
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("click", function() {
    var dataClass = $(this).data("class");
    // dataClass мы получили равным "js-all"
    $(".js-all").each(function() {
      // пробегаем по всем элементам с классом "js-all" и для тех,
      // у кого он не установлен, ставим disabled = false
      this.disabled = !$(this).hasClass(dataClass);
    });
  });
});
```

Вопрос. У скольки элементов с классом `js-all` не установлен класс `js-all`? Правильно. Ни у одного.

Ваш код должен выглядеть, примерно, так

```js
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("click", function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $(".js-all").each(function() {
      this.disabled = !checked;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checker squaredFour">
  <label>
     <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-test" data-class="js-a">
     <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
   </label>
</div>

<label for="inputReturn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Обратно</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker js-all js-a" id="inputReturn" disabled>
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
```

А еще лучше так

```js
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("click", function() {
    $(".js-all").prop({disabled: !this.checked});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checker squaredFour">
  <label>
     <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-test" data-class="js-a">
     <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
   </label>
</div>

<label for="inputReturn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Обратно</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker js-all js-a" id="inputReturn" disabled>
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Шикарный ответ. Потому что с комментариями! Помогает разобраться. Побольше бы таких людей.

Comment: @AlexSorokin Если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как правильный

Answer (score 1):

У вас при событии click в this.checked приходит состояние чекбокса. Вот исходя из этого состояния и выставляйте свойство disabled у инпута:

```js
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").on("click", function(e) {
    var checked = this.checked;
    var dataClass = $(this).data("class");
    $(".js-all").each(function() {
      this.disabled = !checked;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checker squaredFour">
  <label>
     <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-test" data-class="js-a">
     <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
   </label>
</div>

<label for="inputReturn" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Обратно</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker js-all js-a" id="inputReturn" disabled>
  <input type="button" value="">
</div>
```